# How does spell that you can cast "spontaneously" granted by the Channel the Gift spell work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, spellcasting

I am wondering about the casting time of the spell granted by [*channel the gift*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/channel-the-gift/) when you target yourself and if it should count as a spell like ability:

> If you target yourself with this spell, you may spontaneously cast any prepared spell of 3rd level or lower without expending its spell slot on your next turn (this aspect of the spell has no effect if you are a spontaneous caster). The spell that’s cast after *channel the gift* cannot have a casting time longer than 1 full round.

It fails to say what the action to cast the spell is or if it should be treated like an SLA.

Part of why I'm asking about SLA is the meaning of "spontaneously" from google search:

> without apparent external cause or stimulus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the description of *Channel the Gift*, it says:

> If you target yourself with this spell, you may **spontaneously cast** any prepared spell of 3rd level or lower without expending its spell slot on your next turn (this aspect of the spell has no effect if you are a **spontaneous caster**).

*Spontaneous* has a defined meaning in relation to spellcasting in Pathfinder.

eg, [Cleric](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/CLERIC/#Spontaneous_Casting) has this ability:

> Spontaneous Casting
>   A good cleric (or a neutral cleric of a good deity) can channel stored spell energy into healing spells **that she did not prepare ahead of time.** The cleric can “lose” any prepared spell that is not an orison or domain spell in order to cast any cure spell of the same spell level or lower (a cure spell is any spell with “cure” in its name).

ie, *spontaneous* casting is just casting a spell without having to prepare it first.

About casting time, the spell says:

> The spell that’s cast after channel the gift **cannot have a casting time longer than 1 full round.**

This implies that the spell takes just as long to cast as it normally would.

---

*(I see very little advantage to casting this spell on yourself - you still need to have prepared whichever spell you are using it for. So, you're trading a 3rd level spell slot (for Channel the Gift) for an extra casting of another 1st-3rd level spell that you have already prepared.)*

Comment: This definition clearly isnt being used here as the spell must already be prepared

Comment: I disagree. Why else would it say *"this aspect of the spell has no effect if you are a spontaneous caster"*?